# Why my javascript Comparison Operators code working incorrect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Why my javascript Comparison Operators code working incorrect ?

On this code requests_withdraw is `300` and money is

`1200.34` but when i tested code it's will alert `not enough money for withdraw` Why ? how can i do ?

```html
<script>
reqests_withdraw = "300";
money = "1200.34";
if(reqests_withdraw > money)
{
    alert("not enough money for withdraw");
}
else
{
 alert("OK");
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're comparing **strings**, not numbers.

Comment: btw, it is working correctly.

Comment: I'm sure there's a dupe for this... Can't find one though.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing **string** not **numbers**

Remove the double quotes

```js
reqests_withdraw = 300;
money = 1200.34;
if (reqests_withdraw > money) {
  alert("not enough money for withdraw");
} else {
  alert("OK");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you are comparing strings in your code, you need to use `parseFloat()`

```html
<script>
reqests_withdraw = "300";
money = "1200.34";
if(parseFloat(reqests_withdraw) > parseFloat(money))
{
    alert("not enough money for withdraw");
}
else
{
 alert("OK");
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is good if he is going to collect input from the html in a textarea but if not Weedoze's answer is better. There's no need to parse a string into a number when you can start with a number.

Comment: that would be the probable case I suppose, why would anyone initialize numbers as strings in quotes

Comment: ya the only reason to do that would be as a placeholder to make sure the javascript is all valid before integrating it with html. I vote its a beginner's error though

Answer (score 1):

Above have already been answered, but as an option, another way to turn a string into a number

```
    reqests_withdraw = "300";
    money = "1200.34";
    if(+reqests_withdraw > +money)
    {
        alert("not enough money for withdraw");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("OK");
    }
```

Comment: Upvote because i didn't know that

Answer (score 0):

Yo have string there and it compares first letter. if there are equal it compare second letter.

```
"330.23">"340"
false
"330.23">"240"
true
"330.23">"2040"
true
```

to use them in `if` statement convert values to float using `parseFloat`